# find elements from the xml file with android

Tags: android, xml

I have an xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<etudiants>
    <etudiant>
        <ncin>00112233</ncin>
        <nom>aaaaa</nom>
        <prenom>bbbbb</prenom>
    </etudiant>

    <etudiant>
        <ncin>11225588</ncin>
        <nom>azeqsd</nom>
        <prenom>wxcqsd</prenom>
    </etudiant>

</etudiants>
```

The user enter the ncin in an EditText and click search ; the "nom" displayed in an TextVew if Exist

Thank you in advance

Comment: Accept answers to your previous questions in order to get more answers here...

Answer (score 2):

You can use different parsers , to parse your xml like SAX , DOM parsers
Check here

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

and use it accordingly.